# Can I use a GPL licensed library in my software if its only used in a helper process?

Tags: license-compatibility, license

I found a library that uses the `GPL-2.0` license. I know about the conflicts between GPL, closed source and commercial projects. I am considering to use a GPL licensed library in an executable (helper.exe) that is executed by my main application (main.exe).

I would like to keep my source closed of `main.exe`, but `helper.exe` I would make open source. Is it legally possible to ship my project with this combination?

Thank you!

Comment: When `main.exe` invokes `helper.exe`, what sort of arguments, pointers, structure, are passed between them?  What does `helper` do for `main`?

Comment: `helper.exe /path/to/file` and it prints out a JSON and base64 blob

Comment: How much structure is inside `/file`?  Specifically, how much structure that is pre-agreed between `main` and `helper`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely perfectly fine. The GPLv2 calls this case “mere aggregation”: you can distribute a GPL-covered program alongside a proprietary program without issues, provided you comply with the GPL for the GPL-covered program.

It is not always clear whether two executables form two separate programs, or whether they are so intertwined that they effectively form a single program. The GPL FAQ suggests that two programs are separate when they only communicate “at arms length”. Since your programs communicate via simple command line arguments and JSON documents, there's a very good chance that they are indeed separate.

Personally, I think a good test is to consider the actual goals of the GPL: software freedom. Is an end user actually able to inspect and modify the GPL-covered program, and your proprietary system will be able to use modified versions? If so, very good.

Relevant entries from the GPL FAQ:

- [What is the difference between an “aggregate” and other kinds of “modified versions”?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#MereAggregation)
- [I'd like to incorporate GPL-covered software in my proprietary system. I have no permission to use that software except what the GPL gives me. Can I do this?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLInProprietarySystem)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the links! That is gold worth! Thanks a lot!